# How to remove % character in the URL (Google Chrome)

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I have a small application developed in C# with the main purpose to search something on a specific website based on the user input, using Chrome. But after the user inputs the string and uses the button, the final URL opened in Chrome, containing `%` and due to this, the value cannot be found on that website. How can I avoid this in Google Chrome? Or maybe in C#? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.mfinante.ro/infocodfiscal.html?cod='" + txtCIF.Text + "'");
}
```

Comment: It's part of percent-encoding for reserved characters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters

Answer (score 2):

SAMPLE CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
namespace Rextester
{ public class Program {
 public static void Main(string[] args){
string url = "localhost:8080/Site/List/hello%20test%20A89";
string newUrl=System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
 Console.WriteLine(newUrl);}}}
```

OUTPUT:
localhost:8080/Site/List/hello test A89

Comment: I edited the code as above. You may also find it at http://rextester.com/XZIZ58160